# how to SQL query products _wp_attached_file path by category in Woocommerce database?

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to directly get all image path's of a certain product category from wp_postmeta and I know I have to join it with wp_term_taxonomy to check for its category first but have no idea how to join and group them. When I run

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` where meta_key = "_wp_attached_file"
```

I do get a list of all posts and their attachment but I need the products of certain category only and don't know how to filter them out.